# Does the shell structure really make sense for a high-Z atom?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

The shell structure picture is based on the mean field approximation, which replaces the interaction between the electrons by some mean-field potential. For a high-Z atom, like Fe, or even Ur, is the mean field approximation still okay?

Comment: Actually, i have no intuition about whether the mean-field approximation will get better or worse as Z increases. Anyway, is the mean-field approximation really trusty?

Comment: I've got no idea about its quantitative errors, but the fact that chemistry, in particular the periodic system, which essentially is built on these shells, works with fat atoms, too, indicates it is good enough, doesn't it?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Well, the fine and hyperfine "corrections" in the nuclear system can be comparable to the principle contribution so that is not obvious. But, yeah, it does pretty well in the end.